# Pulling in optional parameters for Emma API using php

Tags: php, json, api, curl

I am trying to get additional parameters from Emma's API using php.  If anyone can point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.  I know that my problem is terminology and thnk I am struggling with the basics and just need to "get over the hump."

I have been able to successfully test getting the basic fields that Emma provides by using get curl https://api.e2ma.net/account_id/mailings and --header 'Authorization: Basic {{public_api_key}}:{{private_api_key}}'

My problem is that according to their documentation (url below), I should be able to include extra parameters (I need to get the with_html_body parameter).

http://api.myemma.com/api/external/mailings.html

The code below gives me the following error:
Error getting member: {"error": "Unable to parse JSON request"}

I know the $data array is the problem.
Any idea if this is my only problem?
I figure I need to pull in the with_html_body field as an array and then CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS the variable ($data).

Amy I way off base?

Thanks in advance for any help pointing me in the right direction.

```
<?php
// Authentication Variables
$account_id = "1111111";
$public_api_key = "99999999";
$private_api_key = "99898989";


// Set URL
$url = "https://api.e2ma.net/" . $account_id . "/mailings";

// Open connection
$ch = curl_init();

$data = array('with_html_body' => 'true');

// Make the curl call
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $public_api_key . ":" . $private_api_key);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$head = curl_exec($ch);
$http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
//curl_close($ch);

// check for errors
if($http_code > 200) {
    print "Error getting member:\r\n";
    print_r($head);
} else {
    /*
    print "Member information:\r\n";
    print_r($head);
    */
    $decoded = json_decode($head, true);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($head);
    echo "</pre>";
    /* 
    */
}
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Typical me, I over-complicated the issue!

All I needed to do was adjust the $url to below.

```
$url = "https://api.e2ma.net/" . $account_id . "/mailings?with_html_body=true";
```

Yes, I feel like an idiot!
But making progress.

Now to put this code in a better form to use on a project.